# Check if ionic app is in dev serve mode(browser)

Tags: javascript, browser, ionic-framework

I use `ionic serve` to run my app on localhost.

how can I know when I'm in **browser** and not in **android**?

I tried:

```
navigator.platform // MacIntel
navigator.platforms // undefined
ionic.Platform.is('BROWSER') // false
navigator.userAgent // ...iPhone... => i'm in chrome device mode
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There's probably more than one way to do it, but a simple one is that `cordova` will only be defined on Android/iOS so you could do

```
if (window.cordova) {
  // running on device/emulator
} else {
  // running in dev mode
}
```

#### Edit

Some text editors and TypeScript parsers may complain that `Property 'cordova' does not exist on type 'Window'.` In order to work around that, you can use the following:

```
if ((<any>window).cordova) {
  // running on device/emulator
} else {
  // running in dev mode
}
```

By explicitly casting to type `any` you can avoid transpiler errors, and still accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: What if you have ngCordovaMocks loaded?

Comment: If `cordova` is not null in the browser, then try `cordova.plugins` instead (worked for me at least)

Answer (score 6):

I found I can use

```
ionic.Platform.platforms[0] == "browser"
```

to check if the application is running in a browser or not.

Important thing, `ionic.Platform.platforms` is set only after `$ionicPlatform.ready` event is fired.

Answer (score 6):

Checking if window.location.hostname is equal to localhost will work too.

```
if(window.location.hostname === "localhost"){
    return 'http://localhost:8100/api/';
} else {
    return 'https://some-api.com/';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()){
  console.log('i am in a browser webview!');
}
```

or

```
console.log(ionic.Platform.platform());
```

That will tell you what platform you are on. Webview or android or ios or whatever.

Comment: `ionic.Platform.isWebView()` => false, `ionic.Platform.platform()` => ios

Comment: ok so you are either on a ios device, or emulating an ios device.

Comment: I'm using chrome device mode on iphone 6 but i'm still using the browser

Comment: yeah but as far as the app knows you are using an iphone 6. that is how emulation works...

Comment: When we use `ionic serve --lab`, it detects devices as iOS and Android respectively. How do I detect them?

Comment: use the ionic.platform methods.

Answer (score 0):

For now, in my Ionic 1 app (using last version 3.9.x, but with --type ionic1), ionic.Platform.platform() when i am in desktop is returning "linux", not "browser". And window.cordova now exists in browser, but you can check if window.cordova.platformId == 'browser'. It seems work here.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little correction to **Mirko N.** answer.

Typescript will actually return error if you use cordova directly or as a child of window object.

The proper answer is to check if window has cordova as own property.

```
if(window.cordova) //returns error "Property 'cordova' does not exist on type 'Window'."
```

---

```
if(window.hasOwnProperty('cordova')) //Proper Check
```

[image]